# Substring for Ints without Having an Integer Expression

Tags: sql, int

I am trying to update values in a database that does not do floats / decimals through the the DB itself. The front end "translation" of the decimals is also inconsistent.

So column A may take 1234 and turn it into 12.34, and column B may take it and turn it into 1.234.

When multiplying two columns together, I end up with a long int that needs to be cut down. However, there's no consistency for the integer expression.

Employee A:
Pay rate: $20.67. In db: 20670
Hours worked: 3.95. In db: 395

`20670 * 395 = 8164650`. 
Needs to be `8164`. `LEFT(rate *hrs, 5) = 8164`

Employee B: 
Pay rate: $18.07. In db: 18079
Hours worked: 8. In db: 800

`18079 * 800 = 14463200`. 
Needs to be `14464`. `LEFT(rate*hrs,5) = 1446`

Is there another way I can reduce the int without relaying on integer expressions?

Comment: Does the DB always store numbers in a fixed width?  Put another way, is the rule to arrive at the actual number always to divide by 1000?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this was somebody's ill-fated attempt at avoiding floating point imprecision and it's just a messed up schema; the database itself is a normal SQL database that supports floating point numbers.

Rather than trying to work with this mess, it's going to suck down a lot of time and generate a lot of totally avoidable bugs, fix it. Create a new schema (possibly a new database) that uses proper `decimal` columns and translate all your data into it. `decimal` and `numeric` are generally exact and do not suffer from floating point error (though the results of doing math on them might). All new code should use this, and as much existing code should be switched over as possible.

***Then turn all the existing messed up tables into views with the same name***. These views translate the decimal columns back into integers. This gives you backwards compatibility with queries you couldn't get fixed (or don't know about), while maintaining one sane set of tables.

For example...

```
create table employee_pay2 (
    EmployeeID integer references(employee),
    Rate decimal(10,2),
    Hours decimal(10,2)
);

create view employee_pay_view
as
select
    EmployeeID,
    Rate * 1000,
    Hours * 100
from employee_pay;
```

Once you're sure that view works, drop the old table and rename the view to the old table name ([SQL Server recommends you drop and recreate the view rather than renaming it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187586.aspx).

Now any old queries will be using the view. You might even be able to use the query log to find stray code that's still doing it the old way.

Comment: Sadly from what I can tell, the db isn't a normal SQL db and doesn't support floats (it also isn't normalized), and I do not own the schema/db and so can make no modifications to it. I was thinking of making a temp table and maybe doing some calc/translation using that, so could still work.